# Netbeans/plugin update and strange behaviour

Tags: java, plugins, netbeans, junit4, netbeans-7

I installed [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) 7.1.1 to my Windows 7 64 bit. Whenever I try to update it, or install JUNIT/SWING plugin the updating process bar freezes.
I read about installing it to a folder where it has write access so I installed [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) to my D drive and start it with admin rights but nothing more happened.
The other problem is that when I exit from [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) it often restarts itself after closing which looks strange.
Does anyone have idea what to do? Has anyone seen the same?
Previously I had [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) 7.0 on windows 7 32bit installed to D:\Netbeans which was working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution. I read everywhere that I have to turn off the firewalls, try to install it manually, or install it as administrator but these were not enough. I had to add netbeans as an exception into every antivirus softwares as well! [like AVG]
Summa smummarum if you have the same problem, do the followings:
1. Install netbeans to somewhere except system diretories [I installed it to my D drive]
2. Add Netbeans to your firewall exception list.
3. Add Netbeans to all your antivirus softwares exception list as well.

I hope it will help everyone who has the same issue.